# Warning relating to GPT while installing Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 15R 5537 alongside Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, freeze, inspiron, gpt

I am receiving the following warning while attempting to install Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15R 5537 laptop which already has Windows 7 installed:

> /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables. Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition table?

[image: screenshot of the error]

I doesn't matter if I click on *Yes*, or *No*... In both cases nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html and http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS version. You can find it on your motherboard's website.